# My animations are not smooth using animations package in flutter

Tags: flutter

am using the animations package in flutter for default animations but by using open container method from a listView item to a screen the animations are not smooth without any errors.

please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the app in the iOS Simulator or Android Emulador? The Simulator/Emulator performance is not representative of real devices, so you should always test the app's performance on an actual device.

If not, are you running the app in debug mode? Debug mode is not optimized, and often the animations will be janky. Instead, try running your app on an actual device and in release mode (`flutter run --release`).

Comment: thank you. it's working now i didn't know that. keep it up.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. :)